# Binding Select Forms in Vuex/Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I am trying to bind a `select` field to my vuex store using v-model – however, while the selection function seems to work when updating the state, it doesn't change what is displayed in the frontend select box.

[image: visual representation of issue]

This is my select tag in the HTML template, there don't seem to be any problems with how I'm iterating over the options):

```
<select v-model="selectedRole">
    <option v-for="option in roleOptions" :key="option.text" :value="option.value">
        {{ option.text }}
    </option>
</select>
```

This is my computed property `selectedRole` which I'm trying to bind to ([following the guidelines for a two-way computed property in the docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#two-way-computed-property)):

```
computed: {
  selectedRole: {
    get () {
      return this.$store.getters['user/selectedRole']
    },
    set (payload) {
      return this.$store.commit('user/setRole', { payload })
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my `user.js` file with the corresponding mutations and getters:

```
export const state = () => ({
  selectedRole: ''
})

export const mutations = {
  setRole (state, payload) {
    state.selectedRole = payload
  }
}

export const getters = {
  selectedRole: (state) => {
    return state.selectedRole
  }
}
```

This is also my first time using Nuxt.js as a framework, so I don't know if there are some issues or documentation there that I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone stuck on this in the future, it was because I was passing the payload through as an object... `return this.$store.commit('user/setRole', { payload })` needs to be:
`return this.$store.commit('user/setRole', payload)`